# Programmatically use visudo to edit sudoers?

Tags: scripting, sudo

I have a sudoers file stored in our svn repo. I want to `svn export` it to `/etc/sudoers`, but can't do it because sudo detects that it was not edited by visudo and throws syntax errors. What exactly does `visudo -f` do, and can I do the following:

```
cd /tmp && svn export <URL>/sudoers &&  visudo < /tmp/sudoers
```

without manual intervention?

Comment: It's not because it was not edited by visudo, it's because it did had syntax errors. Also check the permissions.

Answer (score 10):

It's probably not because it was not edited by visudo, it's because it did have syntax errors. Also check the permissions. It's perfectly fine to edit `/etc/sudoers` without using `visudo`. `visudo` is only there to guarantee exclusive access and check the syntax before committing to the actual file. Having said that, to answer your question, you can do:

```
VISUAL="cp /tmp/sudoers" visudo
```

`visudo` calls your preferred editor with `/etc/sudoers.tmp`, checks the syntax on the new content of the file once the editor has returned and commits to `/etc/sudoers` when happy. By setting your preferred editor to `cp /tmp/sudoers`, you're actually telling it to do `cp /tmp/sudoers /etc/sudoers.tmp`.

(storing that `sudoers` temp file in a a world writeable directory like `/tmp` sounds dangerous to me)

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. Two comments though. 1) VISUAL seem to take precedence over EDITOR, so I would go for that. 2) My version of visudo seem to to not allow any custom editor unfortunately because of security reasons.

Comment: To other over-automating venturers. It's basically impossible to do this. Save a few hours of your life and just do something like this in your dotfiles: https://github.com/Tarrasch/dotfiles/commit/a2f467b6a9e280dd6ba03ccfc909f380dbb354a2

Comment: @Tarrasch, indeed. I had completely forgotten this answer when answering [that one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179445) (where I point out that VISUAL takes precedence over EDITOR).

Answer (score 6):

I edit and deploy `sudoers` all the time. Make sure you do the following:

- Use `visudo -c -f <filename>` to check the syntax before you check it in to svn.
- When you deploy make sure the permissions are `0440` and owned by `root:root` (or `root:wheel` on BSD derivatives).

If your the host you use to check in runs a different OS than the one you're deploying to then you should also run `visudo -c -f <filename>` on the target system before copying it into place.

Comment: Thanks for the visudo -c -f . Using that in my script provided the exit code 1 I need to abort if things are not right.