# Is 'echo "Defaults insults" >> /etc/sudoers' safe?

Tags: sudo

Is this safe?

```
echo "Defaults    insults" >> /etc/sudoers
```

If yes, can I do this?

```
echo "## First line" >> /etc/sudoers
echo "### Second line" >> /etc/sudoers
echo "Defaults    insults" >> /etc/sudoers
echo "### Totally the last line" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Is there a better way to do this incorporating `visudo`?

I'm making a bash script, this bit needs to turn insults on and off.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways in which it can be dangerous:

1. If `/etc/sudoers` doesn't end in a newline character (which `sudo` and `visudo` allow), for instance, if it ends in a non-terminated `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` line, your command will make it:

   ```
   #includedir /etc/sudoers.dDefaults insults
   ```

   which will break it and render `sudo` unusable.
2. `echo` may fail to write the full string, for instance if the file system is full. For instance, it may just be able to write `Defaults in`. Which again will break your `sudoers` file.
3. On a machine with multiple admins, if both attempt to modify `/etc/sudoers` at the same time, the data they write may be interlaced.

`visudo` avoids these problems because it lets you edit a temporary file instead (`/etc/sudoers.tmp`), detects if the file was modified (unfortunately not if the file was *successfully* modified as it doesn't seem to be checking the editor's exit status), checks the syntax, and does a `rename` (an atomic operation) to move the new file in place. So it will either successfully update the file (provided your editor also leaves the file unmodified if it fails to write the new one) or fail if it can't or the syntax is invalid.

`visudo` also guards against several persons editing the `sudoers` files at the same time.

Now, reliably using `visudo` in an automatic fashion is tricky as well. There are several problems with that:

- You can specify an editor command for `visudo` with the `VISUAL` environment variable (takes precedence over `EDITOR`), but only if the `env_editor` option has not been disabled.
- my version of `visudo` at least, under some conditions, edits all of `/etc/sudoers` and all the files it includes (runs `$VISUAL` for all of them). So you have to make sure your `$VISUAL` only modifies `/etc/sudoers`.
- as seen above, it doesn't check the exit status of the editor. So you need to make sure the file your editor saves is either successfully written or not modified at all.
- It prompts the user in case of problem.

Addressing all those is a bit tricky. Here is how you could do it:

```
NEW_TEXT='Defaults insults' \
  CODE='
    if [ "$2" = /etc/sudoers.tmp ]; then
      printf >&2 "Editing %s\n" "$2"
      umask 077
      {
        cat /etc/sudoers.tmp && printf "\n%s\n" "$NEW_TEXT"
      } > /etc/sudoers.tmp.tmp &&
        mv -f /etc/sudoers.tmp.tmp /etc/sudoers.tmp
    else
      printf >&2 "Skipping %s\n" "$2"
    fi' \
  VISUAL='sh -fc IFS=:;$1 sh eval:eval:"$CODE"' visudo < /dev/null
```

Won't work if `env_editor` is unset.

On a GNU system, a better alternative would be to use `sed -i` which should leave `sudoers.tmp` unmodified if it fails to write the newer version:

Add `insults`:

```
SED_CODE='
  /^[[:blank:]]*Defaults.*insults/,${
    /^[[:blank:]]*Default/s/!*\(insults\)/\1/g
    $q
  }
  $a\Defaults insults' \
CODE='
  if [ "$2" = /etc/sudoers.tmp ]; then
    printf >&2 "Editing %s\n" "$2"
    sed -i -- "$SED_CODE" "$2"
  else
    printf >&2 "Skipping %s\n" "$2"
  fi' \
VISUAL='sh -fc IFS=:;$1 sh eval:eval:"$CODE"' visudo < /dev/null
```

Remove insults:

```
SED_CODE='
  /^[[:blank:]]*Defaults.*insults/,${
    /^[[:blank:]]*Defaults/s/!*\(insults\)/!\1/g
    $q
  }
  $a\Defaults !insults' \
CODE='
  if [ "$2" = /etc/sudoers.tmp ]; then
    printf >&2 "Editing %s\n" "$2"
    sed -i -- "$SED_CODE" "$2"
  else
    printf >&2 "Skipping %s\n" "$2"
  fi' \
VISUAL='sh -fc IFS=:;$1 sh eval:eval:"$CODE"' visudo < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 9):

I poked around a bit and seems `includedir` support is available in `sudo` going back a long way (~2001 from what I can tell), so it should be supported in RHEL 5. Look for an include directive in your sudoers:

```
sudo grep '#includedir' /etc/sudoers
```

If you get a result, then ideally you should add and remove files in that directory, and it is usually `/etc/sudoers.d`. This path may be difficult to determine in a shell script.

At any rate, assuming `sudoers.d`, you should add files with permissions at most `0600` in that directory. Something like:

```
sudo sh -c '
  umask 0177;
  filename="/etc/sudoers.d/$1";
  echo 'Defaults insults' > "$filename";
  visudo -cf "$filename" || rm "$filename"
' _ 99-insults
```

(Where `99-insults` is the name of the file to be created in `sudoers.d`.)
Then removing the setting is as simple as:

```
sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/99-insults
```

And indeed, that's what the last part of the `sh -c` command does - remove this file if `visudo` fails its check, so that you're not left with a broken `sudoers`.

---

You can use `tee -a` as the `EDITOR`:

```
$ sudo VISUAL='tee -a' visudo <<<"Defaults insults"
Defaults insults
$ sudo tail /etc/sudoers
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
Defaults insults
```

I don't know if EL5's `sudo` has `includedir` support, but if it does, then create new files in it with `visudo -f`, please.

Comment: >I don't know if EL5's `sudo` has `includedir` support, but if it does, then create new files in it with `visudo -f`, please.
I'm sorry, what do you mean by this? Also, I didn't write sudo because I'm root at the moment.

Comment: @amingilani Look at the second-last line of my `sudoers`: `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` - this allows me to add entries to `sudoers` by adding new files to `/etc/sudoers.d`. If EL5's `sudo` is not very old, it should support this, and you can create/delete files in `/etc/sudoers.d` to add/remove sudo configuration changes: `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/some-file-name`.

Comment: @muru writing a new /etc/sudoers.d/insults is the right answer to the OP's problem, althought not the answer to the question asked. If you would write it down as answer I would upvote it

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I wasn't able to determine if RHEL5 supported it, but now I think it would, so I have added it.

Comment: Talking of unsafe things, you can't get much worse than using a file with a fixed name in a world writable directory. (what if someone created a symlink `/tmp/insults -> /etc/shadow` there).

Comment: create; chmod also leaves a race condition. Better use umask.

Comment: cp or tee may leave a truncated file if there are some write errors.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I still believe dropping a file to such a directory is the best solution. The question now becomes how do I best implement it? Start a sudo shell command (assuming the script is not run as root) that checks whether the file is correct after copying?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas as for the link to a root owned file, 1. I'm assuming that the script is not run as root (witness uses of sudo). 2. There should be tests all around, not limited to: existence of sudoers.d, existence of sudoers.d/insults before the script was run, a final run of `visudo -cf`, etc.

Comment: If he just wants to add `Defaults insults` why going through a tempfile and using visudo. Just `umask 0377 && echo 'Defaults insults' > /etc/sudoers.d/insults` to enable, and `rm /etc/sudoers.d/insults` to disable

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós just for that, sure that's all. But for a general case, where some variable component might be involved...