# Linux, add to sudoers file programmatically

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, ansible

What is the correct way to update the `sudoers` file programmatically? Specifically:

- How can I add `,timestamp_timeout=600` to the end of the `Defaults env_reset` line in my `sudoers` files (to increase the `sudo` nag time to 10 hours), and doing this programmatically and without destroying the system (I tried this once and made my Linux system unbootable and had to reinstall). I have read that `chmod 440` might be important for this.
- I understand that this is dangerous, I understand why it is protected, but these are my home systems where I have a script that runs through dozens of simple configuration changes (and I rebuild those systems fairly regularly also, so it would be useful to me to be able to automate this).
- I am most interested in how to do with this with standard Linux tools that I can put into a `bash` script, but I would be very interested to also see how this exact operation is done in Ansible so that I could roll out simple changes like this to all `sudoers` files on my home network.
- On [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79338/programmatically-use-visudo-to-edit-sudoers) there is a discussion on the `sudoers` file, but I don't quite understand the references to `visudo -c -f`; I *think* what is being suggested there is: copy the `sudoers` file, then make changes to that copy, then `visudo -c -f` to check that the new file is valid, then overwrite `sudoers`, then `chmod 440` on that new file, is that it? I'm not sure of the steps to implement this.

Comment: Changing the `sudoers` file will not make your system unbootable. The worst thing that will happen is that you can't use `sudo` any longer, but booting into single-user mode to fix that should be easy, or at least doable.

Comment: My system because unbootable. It's possible that other things contributed to that, but it was more than a year ago, so I gave up attempting to do this, but I figure, surely there must be a clean and reliable way to automate this (or at least I am hoping so).

Comment: @YorSubs at least configuration files related, you can always boot a live linux and change the file there, no need to reinstall.

Comment: `man visudo` gives you detailed explanations on the use of the command and its options.

Comment: I'll delete this question if you think there is little to this. Do you think this is ok to do what I mentioned above? 1. copy `sudoers` to a temp file. 2. programmatically alter the tmp file. 3. `sudo visudo -c -f` to check syntax. 4. if OK from step 3, overwrite the original, 5. ensure that the file has `chmod 440` applied.

Comment: @YorSubs read the manual to know what you are doing, the option `-f`: `Specify an alternate sudoers file location`.

Comment: I have read the manual, it's not always very clear, and I've seen problems with these files. Plus, if you google on this, I see lots of stern ominous warnings to never do this. Do you do this?

Comment: @YorSubs I was just pointing out that the `-f` option does somenthing different than checking syntax (at least that's what I interpret from your comment). I almost never change the sudoers file, but if I would, I'd follow the advice on the file `# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of directly modifying this file.`.

Comment: Then I think the manual is rubbish, because I think it does check syntax from what I think is going on. Man pages are often cryptic to read, that's why I was using a forum like this to get clarification. I didn't really expect "read the manual" as an answer on here. I was just hoping that someone who has done this might say "do this but watch out for that, and this should work ok, I do it all the time" ... `/etc/sudoers.d/` is another big question mark for me.

Comment: @YorSubs, please don't take it wrong that I suggest reading the manual. Often is the best source to check what the command does and what the options are and what they do, so you don't blindly do something that you read in a forum, that could be wrong, incomplete or outdated. The comment section is precisely for this type of discussion.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, it's fine, and indeed, reading the manual is important, but I'd already done that with my checks on `visudo -c -f` but you seem to have a different interpretation of the meaning there than I do. Hopefully someone that changes these files regularly has a tried and tested means of doing this (nothing complex, I'm just after simple ways that are known to work).

Answer (score 4):

**Warning**: the following works.  Whether it's a good idea to do this or not is debatable.  But if you're going to do it, this is one of the less unsafe ways of doing it.

You can do this by setting and exporting the `SUDO_EDITOR` variable to invoke `sed` with a script that changes the file.  e.g.

```
export SUDO_EDITOR='sed -i -e "s/^Defaults.*env_reset$/&,timestamp_timeout=600/"'
visudo
unset SUDO_EDITOR
```

This, of course, needs to be run as root.   Normally `SUDO_EDITOR` is undefined....but it can be used to tell `visudo` to use `vi` or `nano` or `joe` or whatever you prefer (it has precedence with visudo over the more generic EDITOR and VISUAL env vars which are used by lots of programs.  visudo will use them if they are defined but SUDO_EDITOR isn't).  In this case, we're using a stream editor (`sed`) instead of an interactive editor.

If whatever changes you make are invalid, `visudo` will notice and ask you what to do.  Your choices are:

```
What now?
Options are:
  (e)dit sudoers file again
  e(x)it without saving changes to sudoers file
  (Q)uit and save changes to sudoers file (DANGER!)
```

You will want to use option `x`.  `e` will just run `sed` again, and `Q` will save your broken changes.

BTW, if you need to make other changes to `/etc/sudoers` and there's some reason why you can't just drop a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` then I very strongly recommend testing your changes on a copy of /etc/sudoers (e.g. to /tmp/sudoers) and using the `-f` option with `visudo`.

You can verify that the correct changes were made with `diff`.  If it worked, great, you can run it without `-f /tmp/sudoers`.  If it failed, run the `cp` command again to copy the original file again (i.e. revert whatever your SUDO_EDITOR command did), change SUDO_EDITOR and run `visudo` again.  Repeat until it does what you want.

```
# cp -af /etc/sudoers /tmp/
# export SUDO_EDITOR='sed -i -e "s/^Defaults.*env_reset$/&,timestamp_timeout=600/"'
# visudo -f /tmp/sudoers 
# unset SUDO_EDITOR
# diff -u /etc/sudoers /tmp/sudoers
--- /etc/sudoers    2020-07-18 02:57:35.220317224 +1000
+++ /tmp/sudoers    2021-10-15 03:26:13.048804192 +1100
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
 
 Defaults exempt_group=sudo
 
-Defaults   env_reset
+Defaults   env_reset,timestamp_timeout=600
 Defaults   mail_badpass
 Defaults   secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

BTW, You can use anything that modifies a file here - if you prefer perl or python or even a shell script (e.g. a wrapper script around `ed` or `ex` or some other scriptable editor), there's no reason why you can't set `SUDO_EDITOR` to run that instead of `sed`.  As long as it changes the file given it by `visudo`, it will work.   Be careful about whitespace and nested quoting.

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically, the best approach is to add files to `/etc/sudoers.d` with all the directives you need. These files need to be owned by `root` and have mode 0440. Adding files to `/etc/sudoers.d` brings three benefits: it reduces risk related to modifying `/etc/sudoers` for arbitrary changes; in most cases it means that the system’s default `/etc/sudoers` can be preserved, which simplifies future upgrades involving modifications to `/etc/sudoers`; and it makes it easy to see the changes that have been made to the default configuration.

Adding a file will work even for your timeout setting: `Defaults` lines can be repeated, so adding

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=600
```

has the same effect as appending it to the existing `Defaults env_reset` line.

For this to work, you need to ensure that `/etc/sudoers` contains

```
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This is the default for recent installations of `sudo`, but you can ensure this programmatically as follows:

```
if ! sudo grep -q '^[@#]includedir /etc/sudoers.d$' /etc/sudoers; then
    sudo sed '$a\\n@includedir /etc/sudoers.d' /etc/sudoers > /etc/sudoers.new
    sudo visudo -c -f /etc/sudoers.new && sudo mv /etc/sudoers{.new,}
fi
```

(Don’t try using the `SUDO_EDITOR` trick here, because `visudo` will process `/etc/sudoers.d/README` too, resulting in an `@include` loop.)

Comment: Thanks, the `SUDO_EDITOR` trick that @cas gave me is really great (and he also answers a confusion that I had about why when I set `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` to `vim`, that `visudo` is still opening in `nano`, so I need to `export SUDO_EDITOR=vim`, good to know), but probably `sudoers.d` is the cleanest, most efficient approach. I forgot about the `{.new,}` syntax, great. However, what does the `$a` mean in the sed expression?

Comment: `$a` means “on the last line, append the following text”.